# How to read this advanced return statement?

Tags: php, return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

When I use a function I use standard return statements.

I mean by that that I usually either return `true` or `false` or a variable. Nevertheless I am currently following a tutorial which I understand pretty well beside the return of the here below function.

I do not get how to read the question mark the two dots....

```
public function someFunction()
{
    return null === $this->anAttribute ? null : $this->aFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return `null` if `$this->anAttribute` is `null` else return `$this->aFunction()`

`?:` called [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Writing `null` in first place is used for avoiding wrong assignments typo, like `if ($a = null)`. If you get used to writing functions and constants firts this will lead to error `if(null = $a)`

`===` can be read in article used above and called **Identical**. `$a === $b`  `TRUE` if `$a` is equal to `$b`, and they are of the same type.

Comment: Actually, it returns `NULL` when `$this->anAttribute` is equal to `NULL`, and `$this->aFunction()` otherwise.

Comment: @kiamlaluno thanks. Was thinking about comparison result.

Comment: thank you kiamlaluno for the input !

Answer (score 1):

It will return `null` if `$this->anAttribute` is **strictly** `null`, otherwise, it will call `$this->aFunction()` and return the result of this function (if the function made a return at the end)

Answer (score 1):

It is a ternary operator. The stuff on the left is an expression (like `if (...)`). The next value is used if the expression evaluates to true, and the last value is used if the expression evaluates to false:

```
expression ? true : false;
```

In pseudocode you could write it like this:

```
if expression is true:
    use this
otherwise:
    use this
```

It is often easier to read ternary code if you use parenthesis around it (it is a subtle thing, but when you see a return statement that begins with a parenthesis you know that you should stop and read it properly, instead of either ignoring it or getting stumped for a while and then realize what it is).

```
return ((null === $this->anAttribute) ? null : $this->aFunction());
```

Comment: thank you Sverri. By the way do you know why the syntax doesn't start with return $this->anAttribute === null instead of return null === $this->anAttribute ?

Comment: Well, it does not matter which way you compare the two values. It is like the mathematical equation `4 + 1 = 5`. You can also write it `5 = 4 + 1` and you get the same result. Because of PHP's assignment operator, `=`, some people like to put `null` (and other language constants that cannot be overridden, such as `true` and `false`) first, just in case they mistakenly write `=` instead of `==` or `===`.